# How to combine two strings from a list of character signs

Tags: python, list

I would like to combine 'test1' and 'test2' into 1 string with all possible character signs which are listed in `sent_Str`. It worked, but not the way i actually want it to be. I want the character signs to be between 'test1' and 'test2' so its more obvious that it's a combine word.

here is my code.

```
sentence = ['test1']
sentence1 = ['test2']
sent_str = [ '', '-', '*', '=' ]
lst = []
for i in sentence:
    sent_str[+0] += str(i)
    sent_str[+1] += str(i)
    sent_str[+2] += str(i)
    sent_str[+3] += str(i)
for i in sentence1:
    sent_str[+0] += str(i)
    sent_str[+1] += str(i)
    sent_str[+2] += str(i)
    sent_str[+3] += str(i)
sent_str1 = sent_str
lst.append(sent_str1)
print(sent_str1)
```

the output is like below:

```
['test1test2', '-test1test2', '*test1test2', '=test1test2']
```

but i want it to be like this

```
['test1test2', 'test1-test2', 'test1*test2', 'test1=test2']
```

anyone who could help?

Comment: What should the output look like when `sentence` and/or `sentence1` have more than one element? It's not entirely clear what you expect in such a case. (Should they even be lists?)

Comment: There are now 3 answers, each presenting completely different interpretations of your question in the case of the sentence arrays having more than 1 element. Without the expected output, the question cannot be answered accurately.

Answer (score 2):

```
sentence = ['test1']
sentence1 = ['test2']
sent_str = [ '', '-', '*', '=' ]
res = [s.join(sentence + sentence1) for s in sent_str]
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping sentence, loop sent_str

```
sentence = ['test1']
sentence1 = ['test2']
sent_str = [ '', '-', '*', '=' ]
lst = []
for i in sent_str:
    lst.append(sentence[0]+i+sentence1[0])
print(lst)
```